# Where is there a missing semicolon?

Tags: jquery, jslint

[JSLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php) claims there is a missing semicolon here:

```
if ('onhashchange' in window && (docmode === undefined || docmode > 7 )) {
    window.onhashchange = expandFromLocation;                      
}
// IE7 doesn't support the hashchange event so we fall back to standard polling technique
else {
    poll = window.setInterval(checkHash, 500);
    // Clean-up objects as IE7 has hideous performance
    window.onunload = function() {
        window.clearInterval(poll);
    }
}
```

"missing semicolon"? Where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    window.clearInterval(poll);
} <--------
```